# How to change Boot Screen for Vista

Tags: windows-vista

How to change to boot screen for vista ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are tools that achieve exactly that, namely [Vista Visual Master](http://www.vista123.net/vista-visual-master) and Vista Boot Loader Generator

Answer (score 0):

Stardock has two utilities: [BootSkin](http://www.stardock.com/products/bootskin/) (for boot screen) and [LogonStudio](http://www.stardock.com/products/logonstudio/) (for logon screen)